# Comparing enum to list

Tags: java, list, enums

I have

```
public enum Brand{
BMW,AUDI,FIAT;
}

private List<String> initializeCars() {
car= new ArrayList<>();
    car.add("CHRYSLER");
    car.add("BMW");
    car.add("AUDI");
    car.add("SKODA");
    car.add("FIAT");
    car.add("PORSCHE");
    return car;
```

I need method which will return `List<String>` of cars which are on car list but not in enum.

I tried

```
public List<String> extractInvalidCars(List<String> cars) {
List<String> enumValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (ProductCategory enumBrand: Brand.values()) {
enumValues.add(String.valueOf(enumBrand));
}
for (String s : cars) {
        for (String enumValue : enumValues) {
            if (enumValue.equals(s)) {
                enumValues.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }
  return enumValues;
}
```

But I got `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 1):

the error means you are iterating and modifying a colletion at the same time... that is not correct, on the other hand,
dont mix types... enums are enums and strings are strings

my suggestion

. convert the enum to a list of strings
. do a intersection between cars and the new list of string_enums

example:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of(Brand.values()).
     map(Brand::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then you can do

```
cars.removeAll(list);
```

Comment: Now it's returns boolean I need List<String>